# Enabling Jersey trace logging causes MaxHeaderCountExceededException

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, java-ee-7, glassfish-4, payara

I am trying to debug my jersey 2 app on Payara 162, but on every request, after the trace information is printed I get this exception and the client gets no response:

```
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders$MaxHeaderCountExceededException: Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: 100
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:396)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders.addValue(MimeHeaders.java:422)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpHeader.addHeader(HttpHeader.java:707)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.addHeader(Response.java:1177)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addHeader(Response.java:1221)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addHeader(ResponseFacade.java:579)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.writeResponseStatusAndHeaders(ResponseWriter.java:165)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder$1.getOutputStream(ServerRuntime.java:701)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.flushBuffer(CommittingOutputStream.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:261)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.close(CommittingOutputStream.java:276)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.close(OutboundMessageContext.java:839)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:412)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:784)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
```

In my jersey I app I configured trace as so:

```
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {

public RestApplication() {
    super();
    packages(true, "com.example");
    register(JacksonFeature.class);
    register(JsonProvider.class);
    register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);

    property("jersey.config.server.tracing.type", "ON_DEMAND");
    property("jersey.config.server.tracing.threshold", "VERBOSE");
}
```

}

I enabled the logger in my logback.xml (I have configured Payara to use logback), and I see the full trace info in my server log when I enable it on demand by adding the `X-Jersey-Tracing-Accept` header to my request, but then I get the exception. When I don't add the header to the request everything works but of course I don't get the trace.

I'm wondering if there is anything I can change to fix this or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that tracing adds a [header into the REST response](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#TRACING) for each event.

Grizzly imposes a limit on number of headers in the response.
Payara Server by default defines 100 as `maximum number of headers` in the response. You need to increase this number to allow all tracing info in the response.

To set a higher number for maximum number of headers, you need to use asadmin. There is no option to set this in the GUI admin console, it is missing in the screen to configure the HTTP protocol.

If your configuration is named `server-config` and the network listener is `http-listener-1`, then execute the following asadmin command to set it to 1000:

> asadmin> set
>   configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.max-response-headers=1000

You can use a similar command to set all [Grizzly network listener propertiesoptions](https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html), just replace `max-response-headers` to the name of the option you want to set, using `-` as a word separator instead of camel case.

Comment: thanks @OndrejM, I'll try it, though I'm pretty certain the number of headers is in single figures, so adding 1 more would not bring it close to 100.

Comment: yes it worked! I misunderstood your answer, I thought you meant it would add one header to the response, but it adds 1 header "per event" which is in fact lots and lots of extra headers, that's why it was going over 100. Thanks!